# How to cache items within a filterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, filterattribute

How could I use caching to maybe help this attribute along?  Mainly not having to make a lot of calls to container.GetService and getting the user.  could I put some caching into place that would cache the identity as the key and the planner as the value and just look it up?

```
    public class AdminsAndProgramManagersOnlyAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public AdminsAndProgramManagersOnlyAttribute()
    {
        Order = 1; //Must come AFTER AuthenticateAttribute
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var userRepository = GlobalApplication.container.GetService<IRepository<ProjectPlannerInfo>>();
        var identity = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity;
        var planner = userRepository.GetAll().WhereEmailIs(identity.Name);

        if (!planner.IsInRole("Db Admin") || planner.ProgramManager == 1)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("error", new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Error", action = "InsufficientPrivileges", reason = "Contract" }));
        }
    }
}
```

soo...

something like this?

```
 public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var identity = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity;

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Cache[identity.Name] == null)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Cache["repo"] == null)
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Cache.Add("repo", GlobalApplication.container.GetService<IRepository<ProjectPlannerInfo>>(), null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
            }

            var userRepository = filterContext.HttpContext.Cache["repo"] as IRepository<ProjectPlannerInfo>;

            filterContext.HttpContext.Cache.Add(identity.Name, userRepository.GetAll().WhereEmailIs(identity.Name), null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
        }

        var planner = filterContext.HttpContext.Cache[identity.Name] as ProjectPlannerInfo;

        if (!planner.IsInRole("Db Admin") || planner.ProgramManager == 1)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("error", new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Error", action = "InsufficientPrivileges", reason = "Contract" }));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the built-in cache:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Cache
```